# How to set GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH correctly and add the plugin into Gazebo_ros?

Tags: gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi, I am using gazebo to simulate a sonar. Thus I will use `hector_sonar_plugin`. While after I install the hector plugins from source and call it in my sdf, errors come.

At first, an error appear asking me to add `libhector_sonar_plugin.so` to `gazebo_ros package`.

I cannot understand it and thought it cannot find the plugin. Thus,I use

```
export GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH=`pwd`:$GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH
```

to add `hector_plugin` folder into path, then more error come:

```
Error [Plugin.hh:156] Failed to load plugin libRayPlugin.so: libRayPlugin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[FATAL] [1464103865.820981859]: A ROS node for Gazebo has not been initialized, unable to load plugin. Load the Gazebo system plugin 'libgazebo_ros_api_plugin.so' in the gazebo_ros package)
```

Could someone tell me how to set the `GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH` correctly (or reset it correctly)? And if I want to use plug-Ins such as hector's, what should I do? (just copy .so to the model folder or ...?)

I am using Indigo full desktop, and thus version should be gazebo2

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13391/how-to-set-gazebo_plugin_path-correctly-and-add-the-plugin-into-gazebo_ros-?/) by [wyxf007](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2601/wyxf007/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2016-05-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Aiven92](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2471/aiven92/) on 2016-05-27**:
Can you show line of SDF file, where you include plugin ? Frequent problem is a relative path to the plugin.

**Comment by [Weiwei](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2623/weiwei/) on 2016-05-28**:
Can you check out the current GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH? Run $echo $GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH to see whether the path is right.

**Comment by [wyxf007](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2601/wyxf007/) on 2016-05-28**:
I just use

```
    <plugin name="gazebo_ros_sonar_data" filename="libhector_gazebo_ros_sonar.so">
      <gaussianNoise>0.005</gaussianNoise>
      <topicName>radiofence</topicName>
      <frameId>radiofence1</frameId>
    </plugin>
  </sensor>
```

to call the plugin in my sensor sdf file.

**Comment by [wyxf007](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2601/wyxf007/) on 2016-05-28**:
After echo GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH in Terminal, I just get the result

GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH

**Comment by [Aiven92](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2471/aiven92/) on 2016-05-28**:
I have zero string result of echo $GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH, but I'm use ABSOLUTE path to the plugin *.so file and all work fine.

**Comment by [wyxf007](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2601/wyxf007/) on 2016-05-30**:
Could you tell me how to use the ABSOLUTE path? do changes in URDF file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

as already mentioned previously you can see your current GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH by the command `echo` `$GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH`. The path should point directly to the folder **where the .so file is located** (for example the build folder).

the `export` `GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH=´pwd´:$GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH` doesn't overwrite the path it just append the current directory(pwd) to the variable. (you can also use $PWD which is handier) Resulting you have a mess after several tries. In addition, **export is just temporary** and depends on the current terminal. (don't confuse yourself with too many tabs / terminals)

To **clean the variable** use `unset` `GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH`
, then check again the variable: `echo` `$GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH` (no nothing should be returned)

Now you have to navigate in terminal to the folder where the .so file is located (since pwd is the current folder). After using `export` `GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH=$PWD` your variable should be set correctly. (overwrites existing values)

If you want to **append your path to the variable** use `export` `GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH=$PWD:$GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH`.

(Hint: you can also **set the path directly** for example: `export`  `GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH=/home/#USERNAME#/Documents/testplugin/build`)

To have the GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH **permanent** you can include the "export xx=xx" line into your `~/.bashrc` file

Edit/Remark:

The default gazebo plugins are loading since **gazebo is sourcing its default environment variables before the start**. This is carried out using the file `/usr/share/gazebo/setup.sh` or `/usr/share/gazebo-X.X/setup.sh`(the X.X is your respective gazebo version)

To be aware of this behavior and be able to see its default values, you can use `source` `/usr/share/gazebo/setup.sh`

Again, to have this permanent in every console instance, add the line to your .bashrc file.

---

Originally posted by [m4k](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2610/m4k/) with karma: 61 on 2016-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wyxf007](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2601/wyxf007/) on 2016-06-02**:
Thank you!  I was quite confused why echo GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH just return a same name a same name, even if the gazebo default plugin setting still works. But at least I can use your method now.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this and found it to be effective. If you want others to run your code conveniently, you might consider using **relative paths**. I achieved this through ros2 humble **.launch.py** file.

The main approach is by utilizing `AppendEnvironmentVariable` and `get_package_share_directory`

```
import os

from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch.actions.append_environment_variable import AppendEnvironmentVariable

def generate_launch_description():
    # Set Gazebo plugin path
    append_environment = AppendEnvironmentVariable(
        'GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH',
        os.path.join(os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('pb_rm_simulation'), 'meshes', 'obstacles', 'obstacle_plugin', 'lib'))
    )

    ld = LaunchDescription()

    # Set environment variables
    ld.add_action(append_environment)

    return ld
```

then you can use your own gazebo plugin conveniently. Like these:

```
<model name="turtlebot3_drl_obstacle1">
  <plugin name="obstacle1" filename="libobstacle1.so"/>
  <include>
    <pose>1 -2.5 0.4 0 0 0</pose>
    <uri>model://obstacles/obstacle1</uri>
  </include>
</model>
```

Hoping that it will be helpful for you :)